# How to use python selenium find_element_by_xpath find out above key word

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to find a string.  But it doesn't seem to work.

HTML：

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="?cz=del&wbid=7683290543&zjt=aaa&lx=CNAME&xl=%C4%AC%C8%CF&fs=" onSubmit="return b_ifsf('delete？');" id="form1">
<td style="width:120px">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="aaa.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com." >
<input type="submit" name="rpt$btnDelete" value="delete" />
</td>
</form>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="?cz=del&wbid=2324242122&zjt=bbb&lx=CNAME&xl=%C4%AC%C8%CF&fs=" onSubmit="return b_ifsf('delete？');" id="form1">
<td style="width:120px">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com." >
<input type="submit" name="rpt$btnDelete" value="delete" />
</td>
</form>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="?cz=del&wbid=2324242553&zjt=ccc&lx=CNAME&xl=%C4%AC%C8%CF&fs=" onSubmit="return b_ifsf('delete？');" id="form1">
<td style="width:120px">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="ccc.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com." >
<input type="submit" name="rpt$btnDelete" value="delete" />
</td>
</form>
```

How to find out the key word **bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.** and then hit submit to delete it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a contiguous HTML excerpt, is it? Please post it including `<form>`.

Comment: Please show your code, more html and the URL if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EVNRaja's solution was in the right direction.

To locate the text **bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.** then click the associated element with *value* attribute as **delete** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *xpath* and `click()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='form1' and @name='form1']//input[@name='ip' and @value='bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.']//following::input[1]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `submit()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='form1' and @name='form1']//input[@name='ip' and @value='bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.']//following::input[1]").submit()
  ```

Comment: following::input[1] .... in bbb.xxx.com ....
if delete ccc.xxx.com it will be following::input[2] .....
  
```... may be input[2] or input[3] ........```
so it maybe can not work in program .....

Comment: Well, **No**, irrespective of being `aaa.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.`, `bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.` or `ccc.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.` which is our main criteria to identify the reference `<input>` node, will be always followed by the respective delete related `<input>` row. So this solution would work flawless.

Comment: HI ....
is work thinks ....
```driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@value, "ddd.XXX.cc.a.bdydns.com.")]//following::input[1]').click()```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to identify is quoted as hidden element.

The html code you have provided:
`<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com." >`

All the hidden elements in a browser may have a purpose.
Example:

Consider there is text-field and it doesn't numeric values as input, if end-user enters any numeric values there will be an error code displays next to the text-field. 
Here, until we enter a numeric text the error message (text inside html tag element) will be hidden.

In the html code you have shared, the value which you want to inspect was quoted inside input tag and has a `type="hidden" name="ip" value="bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com."`, we can write a compound xpath as follows:

A example with multiple compound statements:
`//input[@type = 'hidden' and @name = 'ip' and contains(@value, 'bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.')]/following-sibling::input`

or
A Simple example:
`//input[contains(@value, 'bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.')]/following-sibling::input`

With this xpath code we can directly identify the submit and in the next step you can click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a css selector combination of:

```
[value='bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.'] + input
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[value='bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.'] + input").click() #.submit()
```

The first part is an attribute = value css selector then the "+" is an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), followed by an element selector; saying, find `input` tag element that is an adjacent sibling element to element with attribute `value` having value of `bbb.xxx.com.a.bdydns.com.`